# Can we have math layouting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Several other communities (in particular [Stats](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/3512) and [Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/166), which are closely related to Biofx.SE) have MathJax support.

This would be highly desirable here as well, since pseudocode and equations abound in bioinformatics.

Case in point, my [first](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/65/29) [two](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/69/29) answers would *both* benefit from it.

Comment: If it is pseudo-code or code use the code features inherit from Stack Overflow. For equations it could be, but it has an impact on the loading time of the page and SE is not eager to enable it everywhere.

Comment: @Llopis I disagree, writing equation-heavy pseudocode as code makes it harder to read. Equations are often more appropriate.

Comment: For equations I agree with you. But this require a developer from SE

Comment: @Llopis SE staff monitor local meta sites, that's why Konrad posted here. This just needs to be enabled in some setting somewhere since the infrastructure already exists for other sites in the network.

Comment: SE staff usually enables MathJax if the community shows a use for it. Two examples from one person might not be enough “shows a use”, could you find a couple more examples by different authors?

Answer (score 7):

Examples that would benefit from proper Math support:

- [How exactly is "effective length" used in FPKM calculated?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-exactly-is-effective-length-used-in-fpkm-calculated)
- [How does the BWA-MEM algorithm assign its mapping qualities?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/289/how-does-the-bwa-mem-algorithm-assign-its-mapping-qualities)
- [Normalization methods with RNA-Seq ERCC spike in?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/52/normalization-methods-with-rna-seq-ercc-spike-in)
- [How to correlate two zero inflated bedgraph-like signals?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/87/298)
- [Formula for k-mer coverage](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/2152/298)

Answer (score 6):

Now enabled both on main and here on meta.

Comment: Awesome. Now let’s see if we can actually get people to *use* it …